# How to implement pluralize & other extensions using Playframework 2.0

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

In playframework 1.x there used to be some bundled java extensions for the templating engine:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/javaextensions

I'm looking for the same functionality in playframework 2.0. For example how would I do this?

```
colour${['red', 'green', 'blue'].pluralize()}
```

I am doing this malually now:

```
We have @colours.size colour@if(colours.size > 0){s}
```

the must be a cleaner more reusable way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can leverage the [pimp my lib](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) Scala pattern to implement something equivalent to [Play 1.x Java extensions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/javaextensions).

For example, the `pluralize` method on collection can be implemented as follows:

```scala
// File app/views/pimps.scala
package views

package object pimps {
  class PimpedTraversable[A](col: Traversable[A]) {
    def pluralize = if (col.size == 1) "" else "s"
  }

  implicit def pimpTraversable[A](col: Traversable[A]) = new PimpedTraversable(col)
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```html
@import views.pimps._

We have @colours.size colour@colours.pluralize
```

Comment: Pimps must be written in Scala but they can be used in templates called by Java controllers.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in a java application. I get the following "value pluralize is not a member of java.util.List"

Comment: Are you pimping `java.util.Collection?`

Comment: Yeah i was trying to get it to work on a simple list<object> but i can not seem to get it to work, I also tried the pimping of arrays in the example link in your post but those did not seem to work either