# Relative time for views in Play Framework 2.1

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

It seems like the Play Framework used(?) to have a `since()` function to get relative time (like "4 minutes ago") in views for Play 1.x. This is mentioned as a Date Extension [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.1/javaextensions#date)

However in Play 2.1 this doesn't appear to work anymore. I get `value since is not a member of java.util.Date` ... Additionally I can't find any other references to `since()` (in the context of Play 2.1) online.

Is there a proper/default way of handling this common case? I feel like I must be missing something important since this *seems* to no longer be supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jack suggested a pretty good answer.

Here is a version of his code that might be useful because it'll enable some composition if needed (the `check` function is not composing but could be easily changed to compose and show a more detailed since value)

```
package object pimps {

  import java.util.Date
  import org.joda.time.DateTime;
  import org.joda.time.Period;

  def step(f:Period => Int)(fi:String):Period => Option[String] = {
    def g(i:Int = 1) = i + " " + fi + (if (i==1) "" else "s") + " ago"

    (p:Period) => {
      f(p) match {
        case 0 => None
        case 1 => Some(g())
        case x => Some(g(x))
      }
    }
  }
  val yearsStep = step(_.getYears)("year")
  val monthsStep = step(_.getMonths)("month")
  val daysStep = step(_.getDays)("day")
  val hoursStep = step(_.getHours)("hour")
  val minutesStep = step(_.getMinutes)("minute")
  val secondsStep = step(_.getSeconds)("second")
  val steps = Seq(yearsStep, monthsStep, daysStep, hoursStep, minutesStep, secondsStep)

  val check = 
    (p:Period) =>
      steps.collectFirst {
        case f if f(p).isDefined => f(p).get
      }

  implicit class PimpedDate(col: Date) {

    def since() = {
      val period: Period = new Period(new DateTime(col), DateTime.now);
      check(period)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, for now we stop at the first matching level, and also we repeat the getter (getYears if matching will be called twice).

Nevertheless, another thing to note is the usage of `implicit class` which has been introduced in Scala 2.10 to ease the pimping

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew there had to be a better way to write the scala.

Comment: It's not yet perfect, but I tried to decompose the code, just to enable different recompositions easily.

Answer (score 2):

The `since()` method is unavailable since beginning of the 2.0 branch.

Not a direct answer, but if it's possible I'd suggest to use JavaScript plugin for this task for an example: [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) reasons:

- It doesn't require calculating it in the controller
- You can cache your site (for an example in the memory) for long time, and `since` time will be still displayed correctly as it's updated on the client-side.
- It auto updates even without page refresh (like here, on the Stack Overflow)

Comment: Nice client side alternative. And indeed, very relevant for long-lived pages

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this isn't possible to do any more (by default in Play2.1). Please correct me if I am wrong. Here's how I recreated it. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773212/how-to-implement-pluralize-other-extensions-using-playframework-2-0) I "pimped" the "Date" class:

// File app/views/pimps.scala

```
package views


package object pimps {

  import java.util.Date
  import org.joda.time.DateTime;
  import org.joda.time.Period;

  class PimpedDate(col: Date) {

    def since() = {
      def addS(b: Int) = if (b == 1) "" else "s"

      val now: DateTime = new DateTime();
      val period: Period = new Period(new DateTime(col), now);
      var r: String = "";

      if (period.getYears() > 0) {
        r = period.getYears() + " year" + addS(period.getYears()) + " ago";
      } else if (period.getWeeks() > 0) {
        r = period.getWeeks() + " week" + addS(period.getWeeks()) + " ago";
      } else if (period.getMonths() > 0) {
        r = period.getMonths() + " month" + addS(period.getMonths()) + " ago";
      } else if (period.getDays() > 0) {
        r = period.getDays() + " day" + addS(period.getDays()) + " ago";
      } else if (period.getHours() > 0) {
        r = period.getHours() + " hour" + addS(period.getHours()) + " ago";
      } else if (period.getMinutes() > 0) {
        r = period.getMinutes() + " minute" + addS(period.getMinutes()) + " ago";
      } else {
        r = period.getSeconds() + " second" + addS(period.getSeconds()) + " ago";
      }

      r
    }
  }

  implicit def pimpDate(col: Date) = new PimpedDate(col)
}
```

Then in my view I can just import the above:

```
@import views.pimps._
```

and then use `since()` just as you could in Play1

```
<td>@record.created_on.since()</td>
```

Please comment/answer if there's a better way to do this or write the scala code...

Comment: did you mix up weeks and months or did I misunderstand?