# What package do I import to use the Play Framework javaextensions? specifically 'since()'

Tags: java, date, time, playframework

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
public String tminus(Long id) {
   Plan myEntity = Entity.find.byId(id);
   String timeAgo = myEntity.checkInTime.since();

   return "timeago";
}
```

I'm getting this error when I try to use the since() method:

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: method since()] [location: class java.util.Date]
```

Comment: this is the [Play javaextension](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/javaextensions#asincea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about PlayFramework 1.x? If that is the case you can use Java extensions in your groovy template:

```
${myDate.since(...)}
```

You can also use the java extensions in your rythm template if you use [Rythm plugin](http://playframework.org/modules/rythm):

```
@myDate.since(...)
```

If you want to use Java extensions in your Java program, you have to do it like this way:

```
templates.JavaExtensions.since(myData, ...)
```

Comment: AND I am trying to use the since() on a date in my model class

Comment: I am not sure but does play 2 even support java extensions?

Comment: well basically all i need to do is be able to subtract two dates and get the difference.  whats the best way to do that in Play 2.1.1?

Comment: ...I just checked and you are right.  2.1.1 does not support javaextensions

Comment: If you need to substract two dates, you can either go https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/JavaExtensions.java#L190 to see how play1 implement this method. Or you can use 3rd party lib e.g. joda date utilities

Comment: What I found [here][1] by biesior

The `since()` method is unavailable since beginning of the 2.0 branch.

Most would suggest using a JavaScript plugin for this task for example: [timeago jQuery plugin][2] 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058718/relative-time-for-views-in-play-framework-2-1
  [2]: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called date in java.until.Date.